# Send Spry Validation Forms using PHP

Tags: php, forms

Well, Im facing a php contact form problem. I dont know much about php too, so this make stuff harder.

Well, I've done a contact form in another page of my website it is working ok. But this second form it does not send the the form to my email.

Here is the code:

```
<form name="orcform" method="post" action="http://www.bmvaluminios.com/formorcamento.php">
    <span id="orcnome">
      <label for="nome"></label>
      <input name="nome" type="text" class="round_corners" id="nome" value="">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">obrigatório</span></span>
    <span id="orctelefone">
      <label for="telefone"></label>
      <input name="telefone" type="text" class="round_corners" id="telefone" value="">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">obrigatório</span></span>
    <span id="orcemail">
    <label for="email"></label>
    <input name="email" type="text" class="round_corners" id="email" value="">
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">obrigatório</span><span   class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">formato inválido.</span></span>
<span id="orclocalidade">
      <label for="localidade"></label>
      <input name="localidade" type="text" class="round_corners" id="localidade" value="">
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">obrigatório</span></span>        </p>
    <p><span id="orcconselho">
      <label for="conselho"></label>
      <input name="conselho" type="text" class="round_corners" id="conselho" value="">
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">obrigatório</span></span>        </p>
    <p><span id="orcassunto">
    <label for="assunto"></label>
    <textarea name="assunto" cols="47" rows="15" class="round_corners_text_area" id="assunto" value=""></textarea>
    <span id="countorcassunto">&nbsp;</span><span class="textareaMaxCharsMsg">demasiados caracteres</span></span></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="orcsubmit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

And my PHP code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=obrigado.html">
<title>Orçamento Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$name=addslashes($_POST['nome']);
$phone=addslashes($_POST['telefone']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['email']);
$localidade=addslashes($_POST['localidade']);
$conselho=addslashes($_POST['conselho']);
$assunto=addslashes($_POST['assunto']);

// you can specify which email you want your contact form to be emailed to here

$toemail = "geral@bmvaluminios.com";
$subject = "Pedido de orçamento desde BMV Alumínos.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
        ."From: \"".$name."\" <".$email.">\n"
        ."Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

$body = "Nome: ".$nome."<br>\n"
        ."Telefone: ".$telefone."<br>\n"
        ."Email: ".$email."<br>\n"
        ."Localidade: ".$localidade."<br>\n"
        ."Contacto: ".$contacto."<br>\n"
        ."Assunto:<br>\n"
        .$assunto;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $_POST );

if (!ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$", $email))
{
echo "That is not a valid email address.  Please return to the"
       ." previous page and try again.";
exit;
}

mail($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo "Thanks for submitting your assunto";



?>

</body>
</html>
```

And the page which has the form,

http://www.bmvaluminios.com/orcamentos.html

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: As I try to submit the form I see the "Please return to the previous page" for a few seconds and then it redirects me to the success page.

Comment: can you just bypass the `if (!ereg` part for a moment to see if it is causing the problem?

Comment: Plus ereg function was DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Use preg_match() instead.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help @Saturnix, i've bypassed the 'if (!ereg' part by deleting the following lines if '(!ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$", $email))
{
echo "That is not a valid email address.  Please return to the"
       ." previous page and try again.";
exit;
}' and i still don't receive nothing.

Comment: Thank you for helping out @AaronJiang I have changed to perg_match like you said by modifying the following line 'if (!preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$", $email))' and i had no luck. perhaps i am doing it wrong? thank you